# Symmetrical histograms

Tags: r, histogram

I want to make a number of symmetrical histograms to show butterfly abundance through time. Here's a site that shows the form of the graphs I am trying to create: http://thebirdguide.com/pelagics/bar_chart.htm

For ease, I will use the iris dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5) 
g + coord_fixed(ratio = .003)
```

Essentially, I would like to mirror this histogram below the x-axis.  Another way of thinking about the problem is to create a horizontal violin diagram with distinct bins.  I've looked at the plotrix package and the ggplot2 documentation but don't find a solution in either place.  I prefer to use ggplot2 but other solutions in base R, lattice or other packages will be fine.

Comment: Would you mind providing the `head()` of your actual data? My guess is that your plotting problem is more of a data manipulation problem. Also, cool problem and goals!

Comment: Herb, also, my solution raises several data questions that I'd be happy to walk you though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without your exact data, I can only provide an approximate coding solution, but it is a start for you (if you add more details, I'll be happy to help you tweak the plot). Here's the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
noSpp <- 3
nTime <- 10
d <- data.frame(
    JulianDate = rep(1:nTime , times = noSpp),
    sppAbundance    = c(c(1:5, 5:1),
                c(3:5, 5:1, 1:2),
                c(5:1, 1:5)),
    yDummy = 1,
    sppName = rep(letters[1:noSpp], each = nTime))

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = JulianDate, y = yDummy, size = sppAbundance)) +
    geom_line() + facet_grid( sppName ~ . ) + ylab("Species") +
    xlab("Julian Date")
```

And here's the figure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, Richard!  I'll apply your code to my dataset and get back to you if I run into any snags.  The graphs you produced are exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd browse the [**R Cookbook**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) and the [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) homepage for different options. For example, you probably want `+ theme_bw()` and you'll want to turn off the y-axis. Also, if my answer is helpful, please up-vote it and consider marking it as a solution to your problem. Here's SO's [help file on the having your questions answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)